# Preventing concurrent update of data

Tags: database, user-meta

I have to implement the update of some metadata. An algorithm try alter some global variables in order to minimize a global error function. This algorithm is triggered by users who ratings each other. As users can rate other users in whatever moment, then i am facing with a problem of concurrency. Does wordpress has a builtin method to prevent concurrent updates?

Comment: Yea, you can use the heartbeat api to disable/enable the update button, lock down the user edit screen, or something like that depending on what's already being updated.  You've got some research in front of you, but if you get stuck in the coding, I'm sure people here would be happy to help you with specific implementation questions.

Comment: Thanx Andrew, but  seems the question was not clear enough.